# MongoDB, sort big collection by a field frequently updated

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongoose

I have this schema (using nodejs - mongoose):

```
const Post = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  likes: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    default: 0,
    min: 0,
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true,
});
```

Let's say my collection has millions of these documents and I want to sort by 'likes'. Meanwhile 'likes' is something very frequently updated so I don't think I should use sorting index on it. If I serve that content in pagination using sort and limit, does this guarantee I have good performance on reading the data even if I don't use index? (I know mongo by default uses some algorithm to create in-memory buckets to sort data, when no index is provided)

Comment: Why would the fact that a field changes content often mean that you can't put an index on it?

Comment: @CodeCaster because as far as I know a general rule is that the more indexes you have on a table, the slower INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE operations will be. This is why adding indexes for performance is a trade off, and must be balanced properly. In my case I have an index on timestamp as well in this collection.

Comment: Yes, that's a general rule, but did you try and measure it?

Comment: Not yet, this is next step, just wanted to hear some advice first, talking from initial project design perspective